# How to convert ios app into Xamarin.ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Actually I have an ios app written in Objective -C ,  I want to convert it into Xamarin.ios I followed [This link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/#Creating_A_Static_Library)  but I could not do that , Is there another way instead of this.

Please give me any idea before negate post i am new in xamarin.

Any idea will be appareciated

thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suggest you rewrite it. I've been there before, and it's advised for the following reasons :

1. You can take the rewrite as an opportunity to refactor and improve existing code.
2. Translating code is usually really fast and easy, it's not very time consuming (unless you take refactoring to a decent level and really spend time improving code base).
3. Xamarin gets its full strength from the "Core" projects. The concept you probably know and like already, and made you switch to xamarin. If you just "export" your current code, you won't be able to move classes in the .Core. Re-writing is pretty much mandatory just because of this, because you need to move about 70% of your code in the .Core project so you can re-use it when you'll decide to write for other platforms. If you just export your obj-c code, you will not have anything to share, and Xamarin won't be of any use, apart from being c#.

In other words, that means you need to re-write and "re-think" your architecture, spceially if it's your first time with Xamarin (or almost), because there is a LOT of code that you can put in viewmodels (in the core) and end up with a very lightweight iOS project.

4. Refactoring/rewriting also helps you make sure all your unit tests are working, and it will give you a chance to discover new bugs, and add new tests for better coverage than you already have.

I know time is usually an issue, but I **guarantee** you that it's an investment against technical debt and towards future development time that you will save for android/windows phone/debugging.

Comment: Nope, you may not ;)